# How to convert IA32 'cmp' instruction to Y86?

Tags: assembly, x86, cmp, y86

**IA32** to **Y86**

**ATT Assembly**

I have the following IA32 assembly code:

```
Bubble:
.LFB0:
    pushl   %esi
    pushl   %ebx
    movl    16(%esp), %esi
    movl    12(%esp), %edx
    subl    $1, %esi
    andl    %esi, %esi
    jle .L1
.L7:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
.L5:
    movl    4(%edx,%eax,4), %ecx
    movl    (%edx,%eax,4), %ebx
    cmpl    %ebx, %ecx
    jge .L4
    movl    %ebx, 4(%edx,%eax,4)
    movl    %ecx, (%edx,%eax,4)
.L4:  
    addl    $1, %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %esi
    jg  .L5
    subl    $1, %esi
    jne .L7
.L1: 
    popl    %ebx
    popl    %esi
    ret
```

I'm trying to convert it to Y86 assembly code. I'm having trouble translating the compare instruction:

```
 cmpl    %ebx, %ecx
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that Y86 does not have `cmp` instruction. However, it has `sub`, `push` and `pop`.

So `cmpl %ebx, %ecx` can be converted to the following code:

```
pushl %ecx
subl  %ebx, %ecx
popl  %ecx
```

`cmp` is exactly the same as `sub`, with the difference that `cmp` does not store the result, it only updates the flags. So `cmp` can always be replaced with `push`, `sub`, `pop` (if there's enough space in the stack).