# 8086 Assembler compare two operands without CMP

Tags: assembly, x86-16

question:

> In data segment i have two arrays A,B (DW)  with size 1`<`N`<`20 with some
>   numbers (code runs only  if arrays length less 20), code need to run 
>   in both arrays and check if number in  same index of arrays equal,
>   push them in to stack. Note: Need to do that without CMP.

Example A:

```
A DW 1234,35235,1234,5678
B DW 4532,32735,5678,1234
N=4
```

The stack will be empty

Example B:

```
A DW 4532,35235,1234,5678 
B DW 4532,32735,1234,1234
N=4
```

Numbers 4532 and 1234 goes to stack

My code:

```
DATA SEGMENT
    A DW 4535
    B DW 4535
    SIZEA = OFFSET B /2
    SIZEB = ($-B)/2
DATA ENDS  

CODE SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
    START:   
    MOV AX,DATA
    MOV DS,AX   
    MOV SP,100h      
    MOV CX,SIZEB ;how times loop run
    MOV DX,SIZEA ;to compare sizes of arrays
    TEST CX,19   ;if size of array B above 19 numbers jump to end
    JNP END
    TEST DX,19   ;if size of array A above 19 numbers jump to end
    JNP END
    XOR DX,CX    ;if arrays size not equal jump to end
    JNZ END


    MOV SI,0    ;index of array
CHECK: 
    MOV AX,A(SI)
    MOV BX, B(SI)
    SUB AX,BX  ;if same numbers zf=1, jump to find
    JZ FIND
    ADD SI,2   ;goes to next index (2 because DW)
    LOOP CHECK ;checking next index
    JMP END    ;when cx = 1 jump to end
FIND: 
    PUSH BX    ;pushing to stack equal number
    ADD SI,2
    LOOP CHECK 
END:
CODE ENDS 
END START
```

This works except for length 19,16,14,13,10,9,6,5,2,1

Comment: I wonder why you can't use CMP. 

Anyway, why not just subtract one form the other & test for zero? (you might have to adjust a little for negative numbers, though)

Comment: This is example question of exam in Assembler, i have to do it on next week. In question wrote : Write code without using CMP =)

Comment: The way you use `TEST` does not match your comment 'if size above 19'.

Comment: Ruud, i don't know how to check this by another way, i agree , TEST not solution, need something else.... but with test its half working =)

Comment: A trivial way to avoid `cmp` is to replace it with `push`, `sub` &`pop`. `push` & `pop` can be left out if the changed value of the target does not matter. The change can be automatized easily, if needed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098073/how-to-convert-ia32-cmp-instruction-to-y86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TEST CX,19   ;if size of array B above 19 numbers jump to end
JNP END
TEST DX,19   ;if size of array A above 19 numbers jump to end
JNP END
XOR DX,CX    ;if arrays size not equal jump to end
JNZ END
```

Why don't you use TEST and SUB to test these conditions? The original questions states **1 < N < 20**. The example program already violates this condition. It uses N=1.

```
sub dx,cx
jnz end     ;exit different sized arrays
test cx,cx
jle end     ;exit [-32768,0]
dec cx
jz end      ;exit 1
sub cx,19
jns end     ;exit [20,32767]
mov cx,SIZEB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DATA SEGMENT
    A DW 4535
    B DW 4535
    B_A = OFFSET B - OFFSET A
    SIZEA = B_A /2
    SIZEB = ($-B)/2
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
START:
    MOV AX,DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    MOV SP,100h
    MOV CX,SIZEB    ;how times loop run
#IFDEF DontUseAssDir
    MOV DX,SIZEA    ;to compare sizes of arrays
    XOR DX,CX       ;if arrays size not equal jump to end
    JNZ END
    MOV AX,19
    SUB AX,CX       ;if size of array B above 19 numbers jump to end
    JC END
    SUB AX,18       ;if size of array B below 2 numbers jump to end
    JC END
#ELSEIF NOT SIZEA = SIZEB
# ERR A and B have different sizes
#ELSEIF 19 < SIZEA
# ERR A and B are larger than 19 elements
#ELSEIF SIZEA < 2
# ERR A and B are smaller than 2 elements
#ENDIF

    MOV SI,OFFSET A ;address of array
    CLD
#IF CPU=8086 OR CPU=80186
    ALIGN 2        ;align address for loop if 8086, don't bother for 8088
#ENDIF
CHECK:
    MOV BX, B_A(SI) ;get B(SI)
    LODSW           ;get A(SI) and ADD SI,2
    SUB AX,BX       ;if same numbers zf=1, don't loop
    LOOPNE CHECK    ;checking next index unless equal

    JNE END         ;job done, if not equal
    PUSH BX         ;pushing to stack equal number
    JCXZ END        ;don't loop if cx=0
    JMP CHECK       ;else next index
END:
    CODE ENDS
END START
```

If bounds are fixed, use the assembler to check them.
No need to check bounds for both A and B, if they are supposed to be of same size.
Since SI isn't checked, better place address in SI and use difference between A and B addressses for other MOV.